# tkroot.tk.call() raises an error after making the exe file

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, drag-and-drop, pyinstaller

My .py file is working with no errors. But after making exe file using pyinstaller and when I run the exe file, it gives following error;

```
File "site-packages\TkinterDnD2\TkinterDnd.py, line 271, in __init__
File "site-packages\TkinterDnD2\TkinterDnd.py, line 41, in _require
RuntimeError: Unable to load tkdnd library.
```

I checked the lines mentioned above in TkinterDnd.py and found that it raises a runtime error due to tkroot.tk.call() function.

Please help me to correct this error.

Comment: what are you using `tkroot.tk.call()` for. I have fond that `tk.call()` is normally not something you need.

Comment: tk.call() is used in the TkinterDnd.py file which is in the TkinterDnD2 folder. In my code I have not used that function.

Comment: Hum. Have you tried building the exe using cx_Freeze. I have had issues with pyinstaller and found cx_Freeze to work better in my case.

Comment: It gives ```KeyError: 'TCL_LIBRARY'```. pyinstaller at least generates an exe file cx_Freeze doesn't.

Comment: Not quite right. You can generate an exe with cx_Freeze. You just need to do it in the command line.

Comment: Yeah, but it gave the error on command line and stopped the process.

Comment: Then you need to correct the error. When compiling an exe there can be many problems. Personally I have had to manually copy over the TCL TK DLLs to exe folder and specify many imports outside of the main libraries being imported due to dependency issues. If you do not set up your `setup.py` file correctly then it will fail. You will need to provide the error you are seeing if you want some feedback on that.

Comment: Finally I could generate the exe file using cx_Freeze. Had to copy TCL TK DLLs manually as you said and set up my `setup.py` file. Thank you very much for the support.

Answer (score 0):

When you build EXE with pyinstaller try add

> --hidden-import TkinterDnD2